# How to recognize the type of a click on a QWidget

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

Using the mouse events of *QWidget* it is possible to catch the user's interaction with the widget. However, Qt does not deliver only the resulting action (a click or a double click), but provides the whole sequence of events as it is. Thus, the action should be recognized manually and my question is: How? `QMouseEvent::flags()` doesn't help much, since the only flag *Qt::MouseEventCreatedDoubleClick* is never set, as reported [here](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2015-March/020678.html).

In other words, how to properly emit those two signals, defined in the header file of *MyWidget* (derived from *QWidget*):

```
void clicked();
void doubleClicked();
```

having those slots:

```
void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    ...
}

void MyWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    ...
}

void MyWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    ...
}
```

By properly I mean that if the user double clicks *MyWidget* only `MyWidget::doubleClicked` should be emited instead of `MyWidget::clicked` followed by `MyWidget::doubleClicked`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the same problem before.  I think it is by design of Qt.  This may not be a best solution, but what you can do is to create an **event filter** and 'wait' for a while:

```
bool m_bClicked = false;

bool eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        // Wait for 400 milliseconds
        m_bClicked = true;
        QTimer::singleShot(400, this, SLOT(eventMousePressTimer()));
        return true;
    }
    else if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)
    {
        // Double-clicked
        m_bClicked = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void eventMousePressTimer()
{
    if(m_bClicked)
    {
        // Single-clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest I try to rely more on events than on fixed time intervals (apart from additional monitoring for reliability reasons, as in communications). So, although waiting seems to be the only work-around, I still hope that someone could come up with a more elegant solution.